# can not read property of undefined with Jest

Tags: typescript, jestjs, this, nestjs

ey,
I´m new to testing and programming. I tried to test a function in nest.js with jest, but instead of a result I got only Cannot read property of "undefined"

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'findOne' of undefined

  32 |   findUser = async (userSchemaDto) => {
  33 |     // try {
> 34 |     return await this.userModel.findOne(userSchemaDto);
     |                                 ^
  35 |     // } catch (err) {
  36 |     //   throw new ImATeapotException(err);
  37 |     // }
```

I tried from using other transform, switched out some plugins, packages and config. nothing resolved my issue. I looked all the day for a solution, now I´m more confused than before x.x

my jest.config.ts

```
export default {
collectCoverage: true,
coverageDirectory: 'coverage',
coveragePathIgnorePatterns: ['\\\\node_modules\\\\'],
coverageProvider: 'babel',  coverageReporters: [
    // 'json',
    'text',
    'lcov',
    'clover',
  ],
  moduleFileExtensions: ['js', 'json', 'jsx', 'ts', 'tsx', 'node'],
  notify: true,
  notifyMode: 'failure-change',
  preset: '@shelf/jest-mongodb',
  testPathIgnorePatterns: ['\\\\node_modules\\\\'],
  transform: {
    '^.+\\.(t|j)s$': 'ts-jest',
  },
}
```

my testfile (the last test is my problem)

```
import * as bcrypt from 'bcrypt';
import { Model } from 'mongoose';
import { UserDocument } from '../../../auth/schema/user.schema';
import { AuthDbActions } from '../../../auth/authDbActions/authDb.actions';
import { MongoClient } from 'mongodb';
import { UserSchemaDto } from 'src/mh_backend/auth/dto/user-schema.dto';

describe('Authentification Database actions testsuite', () => {
  let authDbActions: AuthDbActions;
  let userModel: Model<UserDocument>;

  let connection;
  let db;

  beforeAll(async () => {
    connection = await MongoClient.connect(process.env.MONGO_URL, {
      useNewUrlParser: true,
      useUnifiedTopology: true,
    });
    db = await connection.db(process.env.__MONGO_DB_NAME__);
  });

  afterAll(async () => {
    await connection.close();
    await db.close();
  });

  beforeEach(async () => {
    authDbActions = new AuthDbActions(userModel);
  });

  afterEach(() => {
    jest.clearAllMocks();
  });

  test('hashed Password should be a truthy', async () => {
    const testData = 'test';
    const testsalt = await bcrypt.genSalt();
    const testResult = await authDbActions.hashPassword(testData, testsalt);

    expect(testResult).toBeTruthy();
  });

  test('hashed Password should throw error', async () => {
    const testData = 'test';
    const testsalt = undefined;

    await expect(
      authDbActions.hashPassword(testData, testsalt),
    ).rejects.toThrowError();
  });

  test('findUser should give back mockedUser', async () => {
    const mockedUser: UserSchemaDto = {
      email: 'test@test.de',
      password: 'testPwd',
    };

    await authDbActions.findUser(mockedUser);
  });
});
```

and my file to test from

```
import { ConflictException, Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { InjectModel } from '@nestjs/mongoose';
import { Model } from 'mongoose';
import { UserSchemaDto } from '../dto/user-schema.dto';
import { User, UserDocument } from '../schema/user.schema';
import * as bcrypt from 'bcrypt';

@Injectable()
export class AuthDbActions {
  constructor(@InjectModel(User.name) private userModel: Model<UserDocument>) {}

  createUser = async (userSchemaDto: UserSchemaDto) => {
    let result;
    userSchemaDto.salt = await bcrypt.genSalt();
    const hashedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(
      userSchemaDto.password,
      userSchemaDto.salt,
    );
    userSchemaDto.password = hashedPassword;
    // const findDuplicate = await this.userModel.findOne(userSchemaDto);
    const findDuplicate = await this.findUser(userSchemaDto);

    if (!findDuplicate) {
      result = await new this.userModel(userSchemaDto);
      result.save();
    } else {
      throw new ConflictException();
    }
    return result;
  };

  findUser = async (userSchemaDto) => {
    // try {
    return await this.userModel.findOne(userSchemaDto);
    // } catch (err) {
    //   throw new ImATeapotException(err);
    // }
  };

  async hashPassword(password: string, salt: string) {
    try {
      const hashedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(password, salt);
      return hashedPassword;
    } catch (error) {
      throw new Error(error);
    }
  }
}
```

For complete Code, take a look on Github https://github.com/Wusabinga/nest-js/tree/problem-childs

Comment: Why not follow some of the principles of unit testing [as shown in this repo](https://github.com/jmcdo29/testing-nestjs)

Comment: I tried that too, but it doesn´t work at all :(
Found now a solution as mix from 2 troubleshotings.

Answer (score -1):

I found that solution, maybe not the best, but it works for me.

I installed mongodb-memory-server. First test doesn´t pass, but it downloaded the mongodb client.

```
beforeEach(async () => {
    const mockModule = await Test.createTestingModule({
      imports: [
        MongooseModule.forRoot(process.env.MONGO_URL),
        MongooseModule.forFeature([{ name: User.name, schema: UserSchema }]),
        JwtModule.register({
          secret: 'superSafe',
          signOptions: { expiresIn: '60s' },
        }),
      ],

      controllers: [AuthController],
      providers: [AuthService, AuthDbActions, LocalStrategie, JwtStrategy],
    }).compile();
    authDbActions = await mockModule.get<AuthDbActions>(AuthDbActions);
  });
```

so this is Mix Nr1. I used the generated mongodb global config for the uri of mongooseModel.